# Replacing a character with a different one of a different point size

Tags: fonts, fontsize

The following image shows two ways of writing "2009" in Adobe Garamond Pro:

[image: 2009]

The first one is standard 12pt. In the second "2009," the zeros are written with this command:

```
\newcommand{\zero}{{\fontsize{12.8}{\baselineskip}\selectfont o}}
```

i.e., using a slightly larger "o" instead of "0." Obviously doing this manually is of the question. Is there a way to automatically use this "o" instead of a "0" everywhere? A way which works for all sizes would be preferred.

Comment: Not an answer, I'm afraid, but do you *really* want to second-guess your font designer like this?

Comment: I'll second Brent's concern. Moreover, the tilt axis of the lowercase "o" appears to be quite different from that of the "oldstyle" numerals "2" and "9". Attentive readers will likely be distracted and/or discombobulated by a replacement of old-style-"0" with (suitably-enlarged) lowercase-"o" in numbers.

Comment: I think you're right. The lowercase "o" is not optimal. 

Even so, I'd like my question answered out of curiosity. Learning new tricks is nice.