# Auto replacement of characters

Tags: xetex, lua

To make it very simple, I want to change the mapping of keyboard keys and unicode characters, but not by programming. I want to do it with LaTeX.

eg. As suggested by @Ulrike and @Phelype I've edited my MWE.

This was the code provided to me by Ulrike.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua
{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "shuffle",
    type = "multiple",
    data =
      {
          ["अ"] = {"ə"},
          ["ब"] = {"b"},
          ["क"] = {"k"},                
          ["ड"] = {"ɖ"},
      },
  }
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Doulos SIL}%
   [
    RawFeature=+shuffle,
   ]


\begin{document}
अबकड
\end{document}
```

Note - The script used here is Devanagari. The font specified is an SIL font. This kind of input will enable me to convert the data collected in local orthography to be processed in a phonetic script. The font which is used by fontspec is for the phonetic alphabet. I use XeLaTeX, so every character that I provide (with an appropriate font) looks exactly the same. I don't know how it happens in Lua.

PS - I know that my text editor can replace the characters, but I want to do it for full keyboard and not just for two or three characters. So it will be very tedious to do it for every character. Hence changing the mapping is possibly the best solution for my problem right now.

Comment: Are you open to using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: I use XeLaTeX very often, have never tried Lua, but yes, if it solves my problem, I'll use lua

Comment: You need to narrow down the application a bit, I think.  For example, will this be argument or environment delimited?  Will the transformation apply to groups within the main text?  If so, it breaks arguments that specify things like lengths, where `2pt` would be converted into a nonsense unit.  Likewise for color specification.  If not applied to group content, then things like `\textit{abc}` would not be converted.  So try to tell us more about how this would *actually* be used.

Comment: As @StevenB.Segletes commented: what is your use case exactly? Is it ok to use a command or environment, i.e., `\myreplace{abcd}` which is rendered as `pqrs`? Why do you want to do this wihtin LaTeX and not in your editor or with an external script? If you use Linux for example (or Mac or Cygwin in Windows) you can use the `tr` command in the terminal, or `sed` or `awk` or `perl` etc. etc. to replace everything with a single command.

Comment: Are you looking to replace the whole string `abcd` with the string `pqrs`, or are you looking to replace `a` with `p`, `b` with `q`, etc? Please clarify.

Comment: a with p, b with q @Mico

Comment: @Marijn I don't have any knowledge regarding the scripts you have mentioned neither do I have friends to help me out

Comment: @Niranjan - Then you should be using [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498250/5001).

Comment: texgyreheros doesn't have the chars, you need to replace this by your font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I need to use a font in which both (Devanagari and SIL characters) characters are present? Because there is no such font. I usually use one font for Devanagari and another for IPA (i.e. phonetic script).

Comment: yes, such font substitutations works only in the same font.

Comment: See also: [xetex - What is ‘mapping’ and how can I use it to my advantage? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346630/what-is-mapping-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-my-advantage?rq=1) which seems to work without LuaTeX (only need XeTeX).

Comment: @user202729 Thanks a lot for this reference :) I'll check it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, it's not quite ready for release yet, but I will use this opportunity to introduce the upcoming `tokcycle` package (**UPDATE: `tokcycle` package V1.0 has now been released on CTAN**, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle, 
released 2019/08/21).  It helps you to build tools to process tokens from an input stream.  The idea here is that if you can build a macro to process an arbitrary single (non-macro, non-space) token, then `tokcycle` can provide a wrapper for processing an input stream on a token-by-token basis, using your provided macro.

UPDATE: Christian Tellechea has offered valuable insights into how this package may be improved, and so I am spending more time to implement as many of these improvements as I am able. UPDATE: I have listed Christian as a contributor on the package.  He provided bits of code and inspired me to try to make the parsing phase of tokcycle as general as possible.

The package approach is to categorize what comes next in the input stream as either a *Character*, *Group*, *Macro*, or *Space*.  Your job in creating the token-cycle is to specify the LaTeX directives on how to handle each of those four possibilities.

The package provides tools to help you build those directives, whose function it is to process the token stream and place the processed tokens in the output-stream, which is best constituted as a token register (provided by the package as `\cytoks`).

So let us take the problem at hand.  I need to build a macro that can take a single *Character* token input and provide a mapping to a different character (in a different font).  Here is the expandable code I propose for this:

```
\def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto#1\endcsname
                 \csname tcmapto#1\endcsname\else#1\fi}


\tcmapto अP
\tcmapto बQ
\tcmapto कR
\tcmapto डS
```

The mapping need not be to a single token.  For example, `\tcmapto ब{$\alpha$}` is a valid mapping.  The macro `\tcremap` basically says, if I find a remap, use it, otherwise just output the original token.  I provide a remap of 4 tokens as shown above.

So now let's get to the `tokcycle` syntax.  It provides a Plain-TeX supported syntax (`tokcycle.tex`) of macros `\tokcycle` and `\expandedtokcycle` and pseudo-environment `\tokencycle...\endtokencycle`.

The `expanded` version applies `\expanded` to the input stream before `tokcycle` processing (macros can be cordoned off with `\noexpand`).

Also, it supports `xpress` versions of these macros/environments, so that repeated invocations can use the most recently specified directives, rather than having to retype the directives each time.

Finally, there is the means provided, via `\tokcycleenvironment<\environmentname>{}{}{}{}` to create a more permanent environment with its directives locked in place.

For this MWE (using LuaLaTeX), we will use

```
\tokencycle
  {<Character directive>}
  {<Group directive>}
  {<Macro directive>}
  {<Space directive>}%
<token input stream>
\endtokencycle
```

Now for the code.  First, the code to address the OP's problem.  It makes use, in the Character directive, of the new `\expanded` TeX primitive, in the form of the macro `\addcytoks[x]{\tcremap{#1}}`, which will fully expand the remap before appending the result to the `\cytoks` token register.  If your engine still does not support `\expanded`, you can for this case replace that macro with `\edef\tmp{\tcremap{#1}}\addcytoks[1]{\tmp}`.

The other directives are just the package defaults: Group Content is recommitted to the token cycle on a per token basis (`\processtoks`), macros are echoed literally into the output stream (`\addcytoks`), as are spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\def\tcmapto#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname tcmapto#1\endcsname{#2}}
\def\tcremap#1{\ifcsname tcmapto#1\endcsname
                 \csname tcmapto#1\endcsname\else#1\fi}
\tcmapto अP
\tcmapto बQ
\tcmapto कR
\tcmapto डS
\begin{document}
%अबकड
\verb|\tcremap| handles a single token: \tcremap{अ}.

\verb|\tokencycle|  and \verb|\tokcycle| handle a stream of 
  such tokens, including embedded macros.

\noindent\hrulefill

PSEUDO ENVIRONMENT

\tokencycle
{\addcytoks[x]{\tcremap{#1}}}
{\processtoks{#1}}
{\addcytoks{#1}}
{\addcytoks{#1}}
अबकड डड  \textit{बकअ} कड.

Other text for which no mapping is yet given as of \today.

अबक done.
\endtokencycle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I was wondering how you can give such detailed answers and how long it takes to do this. My best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've been working on this about 5 weeks.

Comment: Impressive :-(. My best compliments.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a great idea.

Comment: @Niranjan The package that was used to answer this question has been finished and released.  I have updated my answer to reflect that information.

Comment: @Sebastiano see https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/tokcycle for package release.

Comment: Always my sincere wishes and compliments. But the file tolcycle is a scan pdf http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/tokcycle/tokcycle-doc.pdf? It is not very clear as usual for my eyes. Also the file http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/tokcycle/tokcycle-doc.pdf

Comment: @Sebastiano I guess https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle is what I meant.

Answer (score 12):

with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua
{
 fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature
  {
    name = "shuffle",
    type = "multiple",
    data =
      {
          ["a"] = {"p"},
          ["b"] = {"r"},
          ["c"] = {"s"},                
          ["d"] = {"t"},
      },
  }
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{texgyreheros}%
   [
    RawFeature=+shuffle,
   ]


\begin{document}
abcd
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively you can use `type=substitution` as mentioned in the `fontspec` manual (page 57) - I'm not sure if there is any difference.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help, but I am getting following errors. Undefined control sequence. \directlua
Missing \begin{document}. f
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "texgyreheros" cannot be found.
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "texgyreheros" cannot be found. 
fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "texgyreheros" cannot be found. 
Font TU/texgyreheros(0)/m/n/10=texgyreheros at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found. ]
Overfull \hbox (0.39941pt too wide) in paragraph

Comment: well if \directlua is not defined that you didn't use lualatex (but probably xelatex).

Comment: @Niranjan if your question is about transliteration: with xelatex you could also use a `teckit` mapping. Simply search the site, you will find a number of answers.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Really, *really* bad idea :-)

You can make the characters you want to remap active and redefine them to print some other characters. However if you make, say, `a` active, then `\newcommand` (for example) won't work anymore because TeX will understand it as `\newcomm and`, where `a` gets replaced by a `p`.

I defined a command `\remap` which takes to characters and makes the first one print the second one, and another `\remapchars` command which should contain the `\remap` instructions and then typesets the argument with the new settings and reverts them afterwards to avoid problems. Do not use `\remap` “on the loose”. You've been warned. here you go:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\remap[2]{%
  \catcode`#1=\active
  \begingroup
  \lccode`~=`#1%
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~{\char`#2}}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\remapchars{%
  \begingroup
  \remap ap
  \remap bq
  \remap cr
  \remap ds
  \innerremap}
\newcommand\innerremap[1]{#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}

`abcd'\remapchars{`abcd'}`abcd'

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked very nicely, this might be 'the' solution I am looking for, but it has not completely solved my problem yet. Right now I want to do this with an Indian script Devanagari. It uses inscript keyboard. I purposely omitted these details, because I found it unnecessary in the minimality principles. Unfortunately if I use your code to replace devanagari characters by roman, it does not work, what do you think is the reason?

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, I have no idea about Devanagari. I did a test remapping `देp`, `वq`, `नाr`, `गs`, and `रीt`, and wrote ``\remapchars{`देवनागरी'}`` ([test file](https://pastebin.com/METh1CEp)) but it came out as `p r t ‘q s ’`. As I said, I have no idea about Devanagari, but to me this looks wrong. Can you post an example with the desired output, please?

Comment: @Niranjan Hm... Apparently some of those characters have combining diacritics. The code however only accepts single characters. With `\remap दp \remap वq \remap नr \remap गs \remap रt` and ``\remapchars{`दवनगर'}`` it works. (I think I've probably just slaughtered the Devanagari script...)

Comment: Oh ok. Let me add the exact input and output in my question.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: @Niranjan Sorry, my answer won't work with that. It's just a simple one-way character substitution. Anything more complex won't work. I'll leave the answer here if someone in the future finds use for it, but it won't work for you, sorry. You'll have better chances with Ulrike's answer.