# Is it possible to redefine the character code of space?

Tags: characters, catcodes

If I execute the code `` \tt\catcode` =12\relax test ``
I get:

[image]

I also can emulate the same effect using `\char32` in place of `<space>`. Is it possible to change the character code of `<space>`, so that when I type `` \tt\catcode`\ =12\relax test `` there is another character displayed there? For example, whenever I type `<space>` it displays `!`, which is `\char33`?

Comment: One way is to make the space an active character then def it to char33 (read e.g. TeXbook/TeX by Topic if this doesn't make sense)

Comment: XeTeX has some alternatives e.g. [fonts - Replace a single letter in xelatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620088/replace-a-single-letter-in-xelatex)

Comment: Look at the linked questions (and the double-indirect-linked questions) from that one for alternatives. For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/498250/250119 for LuaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Plain TeX offers `\obeyspaces` that simply declares the space character to be active.

```
\obeyspaces\def {!}%

\tt test

\tt^^@test test

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thou shalt obey thy spaces!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by `user202729`'s comment, I have done the following:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=` \lowercase{\endgroup\obeyspaces\let~=!\relax}
\tt test
\bye
```

Note the `\lowercase` trick to trick `TeX` into using an active space in the definition `\let~=!`.